# Where can I find a list of when I can see something in the sky?

Tags: astronomy, soft-question

My son is very keen on Astronomy but I don't know when there are meteor showers or something else that would be worth going out to the country to see. Last year we went to see a meteor shower, but I only knew about it because I'd heard it on the radio.

Which websites list events that we can either see with the naked eye, or with a decent pair of binoculars? (He doesn't have a telescope because the advice I found on the web was that decent binoculars are better than cheap telescopes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several magazines and websites for the amateur astronomer that include calendars of astronomical events and viewing charts, etc.

You might want to start at Sea and Sky's [Astronomy Calendar of Celestial Events
for Calendar Year 2012](http://www.seasky.org/astronomy/astronomy-calendar-2012.html) or Sky and Telescope's [This Week's Sky at a Glance](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/observing/ataglance).

Answer (score 1):

Google has a good useable interface for this type of information, it can be found ***[here](http://www.google.com/sky)***.
If You own or have access to a cell phone with Android capabilities you could try installing **["Google Sky Map"](http://www.google.com/mobile/skymap/)**

Answer (score 0):

I have been compiling a file every month of current events in the sky for Starry Night software. This appears as a sidebar every month in the Starry Night Times:
http://www.starrynighteducation.com/resources_newsletter.html

I've also put it in a blog:
http://starrynightskyevents.blogspot.com/